# Notation and major confusion with the definition of the probability simplex

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, summation

So it starts like this:

Given a discrete set $N$, the probability simplex over $N$, denoted $∆(N)$ is defined to be:

$$Δ(N) = \left\{ x \in \mathbb{R}^{|N|} \;:\; x_{i} \geq 0 \text{ for all } i, \text{ and } \sum_{i=1}^{|N|} x_i = 1\right\}$$

I guess I kind of understand what it tries to convey, but in practice something doesn't add up.

For example, suppose, that we have $x= \{x_1,x_2\}$ with dimentionality $|N| = 3$ according to the specification above.

Say:

that $x_1 = \{\mathbb{R}_1, \mathbb{R}_2, \mathbb{R}_3\}$
and
$x_2 = \{\mathbb{R}_4, \mathbb{R}_5, \mathbb{R}_6\}$.

How does this summation $\sum_{i=1}^{|N|} x_i = 1$ work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, this is a kind of question that should be answered via examples.

For any set $N_2=\{a,b\}$ with 2 elements the following vectors $x_1, x_2, x_3$ belong to $\Delta(N_2)$:

$$
x_1 = 
\begin{bmatrix}
0.2 \\ 0.8
\end{bmatrix}, \quad 
x_2 = 
\begin{bmatrix}
0.4 \\ 0.6
\end{bmatrix}, \quad 
x_3 = 
\begin{bmatrix}
0 \\ 1
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
For each of them we have $x_i \in \Delta(N_2)$. Of course there are many more such vectors.

For any set $N_3=\{a,b,c\}$ with 3 elements the following vectors $x_1, x_2, x_3$ belong to $\Delta(N_3)$:

$$
x_1 = 
\begin{bmatrix}
0.2 \\ 0.3 \\ 0.5
\end{bmatrix}, \quad 
x_2 = 
\begin{bmatrix}
0.4 \\ 0.4 \\ 0.2
\end{bmatrix}, \quad 
x_3 = 
\begin{bmatrix}
0 \\ 1 \\ 0
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
For each of them we have $x_i \in \Delta(N_3)$. Again, there are many more elements of $\Delta(N_3)$.

**Note** that the set $N$ is actually of no matter for constructing $\Delta(N)$, it is only its size $|N|$ that matters.

Comment: Oh thanks a lot for the input. Then, I guess that any probability distribution can be explained in terms of probability simplex, or say it could be the result of sampling from some $|N|-$dimensional/size simplex distribution.

Answer (score 2):

Well, what is meant under $\triangle(N)$ is the following: if your vector $x \in \mathbf{R}^{|N|}$ has the following properties:

1. $x_i \ge 0$ for all $i$
2. $\sum_{i=1}^{|N|} x_i = 1$

Then, your vector is from simplex $\triangle(N)$. The sum is taken over all coordinates of the vector.

Clearly, if one of these conditions is violated then your vector doesn't belong to simplex $\triangle(N)$.

Comment: So if I get it well, every sample $x_1,x_2...x_k$ is made up of a vector of $N$ elements/categories, whose real values sum to 1, then, each sample has its own probability distribution?

Comment: I didn’t quite get your question. Sampling from distribution $\triangle(N)$ means that you’ll get a vector from $\mathbf{R}^{|N|}$ with two conditions given above.